# Show Editor Content in HTML page

Tags: php, html

I am using Editor to change the Code Design, But when I retrieve the Code using PHP, it disturbing the Complete page Design.

```
<p><?php echo substr($postData['short_description'],0,POST_DESCRIPTION_LENGTH); ?>....<a href="<?php echo SITEURL?><?php echo $postData['seo_url']?>">Read More.</a></p>
```

How can i resolve this.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that the data your are getting through the $postData variable has html elements in it. You should wrap it with the method [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)() to sanitize it. This will also protect you from possible [XXS-attacks.](https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_site_scripting)